# What does sequence keyword exactly do in this Elisp (Emacs Lisp) statement?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I can't get the meaning of the `sequence` keyword.

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
  '((sequence "TODO" "FEEDBACK" "VERIFY" "|" "DONE" "DELEGATED")))
```

I tried Emacs help and googling. Know much better elisp sequence types now. But can't figure out why we can't just use a list of todo keywords and what sequence stands for here. I found only `sequencep` predicate and `org-todo-keywords` is sequence indeed.

It must be dead simple, but my mind can't move over it without an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sequence` is a symbol in this context.

Checking the documentation for `org-todo-keywords`, the first element of the list can be either `sequence` or `type`. Following are the strings for the actual keywords.

For the documentation, <kbd>M-x</kbd> describe-variable <kbd>RET</kbd> org-todo-keywords <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation and the reference! I've read everything except `org-todo-keywords` docs. My mind is at peace now to continue with org-mode overhaul.

Comment: Note that the quote at the start of the value shows you that the value is data, and therefore it means whatever the code which uses the data wants it to mean.  In any case, the variable's documentation is always the very first place to look when trying to figure out the meaning of a variable's value.

Comment: You're right phils, thanks for pointing this out. I've just started with LISP and syntax confuses me all the way and way to often.